# PHP MongoDB find where first item in array ne value

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection with a document like this:

```
{
 "name" : "some",
 "items" : [
      {"_id" : 0,
       "name" : "item name"},
      {"_id" : 2,
       "name" : "item name"},
      {"_id" : 0,
       "name" : "item name"}
  ]
}
```

I want to select all documents where the the first index in items has an _id equal to 0.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you!

Edit:

I've tried this:

```
$items->find(array('items' => array('_id' => array('$ne' => 0))));
```

and

```
$items->find(array('items[0]' => array('_id' => array('$ne' => 0))));
```

Both return empty however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
db.items.find({'items.0._id': {$ne: 0}})
```

This will select all documents where first element in the subarray has _id **not equal** to 0.  If you want to find equals, use this simpler form:

```
db.items.find({'items.0._id': 0})
```